# How to create a app in Bitnami parse-server

Tags: push-notification, bitnami, parse-server

I have hosted Bitnami parse server in AWS as a HTTP service. I am unable to create a new app in the parse server through its dashboard. I also tried a 1 hour demo with Bitnami parse-server in that demo also I am unable to create a new app. How to do this?

https://bitnami.com/stack/parse

I am unable to achieve this through REST API also. Because the demo site doesn't required a credentials to login. The /1/apps API call requires a email/password to create an app.

How to create a app in this demo site?

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami developer here,

Unfortunately, you can not create a new app using a demo site. Note that this app would serve another API. For that, you need to access via SSH and edit the */opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js* file. For instance, you could have 2 apps with the code below:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
//API 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
var api1 = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "mongodb://root:password@127.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse1",
    cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
    appId: "myappid1",
    masterKey: "mymasterkey1",
    fileKey: "myfilekey1",
    serverURL: 'http://X.X.X.X:80/parse1'
});
app.use('/parse1', api1);
//API 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
var api2 = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "mongodb://root:password@127.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse",
    cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
    appId: "myappid2",
    masterKey: "mymasterkey2",
    fileKey: "myfilekey2",
    serverURL: 'http://X.X.X.X:80/parse2'
});
app.use('/parse2', api2);
var port = 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port);
});
//Parse Dashboard                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    apps: [
        {
            appName: "myapp1",
            appId: 'myappid1',
            masterKey: 'mymasterkey1',
            fileKey: 'myfilekey1',
            production: true,
            serverURL: 'http://X.X.X.X:80/parse1'
        }
        ,
        {
            appName: "myapp2",
            appId: 'myappid2',
            masterKey: 'mymasterkey2',
            fileKey: 'myfilekey2',
            production: true,
            serverURL: 'http://X.X.X.X:80/parse2'
        }
    ]
    ,
    "users": [
        {
            "user":"user",
            "pass":"password"
        }
    ]
});
app.use('/', dashboard);
var portdash = 4040;
app.listen(portdash, function() {
    console.log('parse-dashboard running on port ' + portdash);
});
```

Then, you would need to add the lines below to your */opt/bitnami/apps/parse/conf/httpd-app.conf* to set the Apache ProxyPass configuration:

```
ProxyPass /parse1 http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse1
ProxyPassReverse /parse1 http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse1
ProxyPass /parse2 http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse2
ProxyPassReverse /parse2 http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse2
```

and then restart the services executing:

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I will check this in my cloud instance.